# Move .gcda files with Cmake

Tags: c++, c, cmake, gcov

I have a projet compiling with Cmake. I use Gcov to know code coverage during execution on a target.
I use GCOV_PREFIX to change the directory of .gcda files.
But I have only 45 .gcda files in this directory and the rest in source folders and subfolders. (600).

How can i have all .gcda files in this same directory ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem came from the environment variable. I would set the environment variable as a user and start the program as an administrator (sudo). 
Solutions:

- Declare the variable as an administrator
- Launch the program as a user

  ./start
- Start the program as an administrator with the -E option

> sudo -E ./start

Here is the quote from the man page:

> -E, --preserve-env
>                Indicates to the security policy that the user wishes to preserve their
>                existing environment variables.  The security policy may return an error
>                if the user does not have permission to preserve the environment.